# Does pausing a Redshift cluster cancel running queries or are they paused and resumed after?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, cluster-computing

We're dealing with overnight ad-hoc queries on RedShift impacting our early morning flow. I was wondering if setting up a quick 15 min pause-resume schedule before the early morning flow starts would solve that by cancelling running queries or if it would only pause the queries and later resume them.

AWS Docs briefly mentions "terminating queries" but it's not clear if they are snapshotted to be resumed afterwards.

There is of course the solution of improving the ad-hoc queries process but it's much more complex and the pause-resume (or any other way of cancelling all queries at a certain time) would be a more immediate fix to a large problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Overview of managing clusters in Amazon Redshift - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-operations.html) says:

> When you pause a cluster, Amazon Redshift creates a snapshot, **begins terminating queries**, and puts the cluster in a pausing state.

A terminated query is killed and not re-run.

Thinking about it -- if a client sends a query to the cluster and the cluster is then paused, the client would not know if a new query was later created. It also wouldn't wait around for the cluster to be resumed so that it can receive a response to the query.